# Is it possible to use dolphinscheduler without zookeeper?

Tags: workflow, apache-zookeeper, job-scheduling

Zookeeper plays several roles in the open-source workflow framework dolphinscheduler, such as heartbeat detection among masters and workers, task queue，event listener and distributed lock.
[dolphin-sche framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7uL2.jpg)

Is it possible to replace it by using database (mysql)? The main reason is to simplify the project structure .

Answer (score 0):

zookeeper in DS is mainly used as:

1. Task queue, for master sending tasks to worker
2. Lock, for the communication between host(masters and workers)
3. Event watcher. Master listens the event that worker added or removed

it costs to replace zk as mysql.

Answer (score 0):

zk mainly assumes the responsibility of the registry and monitors the application status. zk is very mature in this area and is a recognized solution in the industry. If MySQL wants to do this, the technical implementation cost will be larger, and may not achieve the desired effect.

BTW, their team is currently working on the SPI development for the registry, and in later versions, perhaps you can use other components, such as etcd, to achieve similar functionality.

Answer (score -1):

for now, MasterServer and the WorkerServer nodes in the system all use the Zookeeper for cluster management and fault tolerance. In addition, the system also performs event monitoring and distributed locking based on ZooKeeper. We have also implemented queues based on Redis, but we hope that DolphinScheduler relies on as few components as possible, so we finally removed the Redis implementation.

so now DolphinScheduler can't work fine without Zookeeper, maybe in the future.

**DolphinScheduler System Architecture:**

[image: DolphinScheduler System Architecture]

For more documents please refer: [Official Document](https://dolphinscheduler.apache.org).